# How to get all applications in the exception list from Windows firewall?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Does exist any way to get that list without using the registry working on all Windows versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On XP, create an instance of the [`INetFwMgr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365287.aspx) COM object and enumerate its [`LocalPolicy.CurrentProfile.AuthorizedApplications`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365328.aspx) collection.  There is an example on MSDN (in VB, which you can translate to C/C++):

[Iterating a Collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366181.aspx)

> The following code example iterates through a collection of [`AuthorizedApplications`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365328.aspx) displaying their properties.
>
> ```vb
> Option Explicit
>
> On Error Resume Next
>
> ' IP Version Constants
>
> Const NET_FW_IP_VERSION_V4 = 0
> Const NET_FW_IP_VERSION_V4_NAME = "IPv4"
>
> Const NET_FW_IP_VERSION_V6 = 1
> Const NET_FW_IP_VERSION_V6_NAME = "IPv6"
>
> Const NET_FW_IP_VERSION_ANY = 2
> Const NET_FW_IP_VERSION_ANY_NAME = "Any"
>
> ' Scope Constants
>
> Const NET_FW_SCOPE_ALL = 0
> Const NET_FW_SCOPE_ALL_NAME = "All"
>
> Const NET_FW_SCOPE_LOCAL_SUBNET = 1
> Const NET_FW_SCOPE_LOCAL_SUBNET_NAME = "Local Subnet"
>
> Const NET_FW_SCOPE_CUSTOM = 2
> Const NET_FW_SCOPE_CUSTOM_NAME = "Custom"
>
>
> WScript.Echo("Create the FwPolicy object.")
>
> Dim fwMgr
> Set fwMgr = CreateObject("HNetCfg.FwMgr")
>
> WScript.Echo("Get the Policy object.")
>
> Dim fwPolicy
> Set fwPolicy = fwMgr.LocalPolicy
>
> WScript.Echo("Get the Profile Object.")
>
> Dim CurrentProfile
> Set CurrentProfile = fwPolicy.CurrentProfile
>
> WScript.Echo("Get Authorized Applications Object.")
>
> Dim fwAuthorizedApplications
> Set fwAuthorizedApplications = CurrentProfile.AuthorizedApplications
>
> if fwAuthorizedApplications.Count > 0 then
>
>    WScript.Echo("Enumerating " & fwAuthorizedApplications.Count & " Authorized Application(s):")
>
>    Dim app        
>    For Each app In CurrentProfile.AuthorizedApplications
>
>       WScript.Echo("  Name:             " & app.Name)
>       WScript.Echo("  Image Filename    " & app.ProcessImageFileName)
>
>       Select Case app.IpVersion
>          Case NET_FW_IP_VERSION_V4 WScript.Echo("  IP Version:       " & NET_FW_IP_VERSION_V4_NAME)
>          Case NET_FW_IP_VERSION_V6 WScript.Echo("  IP Version:       " & NET_FW_IP_VERSION_V6_NAME)
>          Case NET_FW_IP_VERSION_ANY WScript.Echo("  IP Version:       " & NET_FW_IP_VERSION_ANY_NAME)
>       End Select
>
>       Select Case app.Scope
>          Case NET_FW_SCOPE_ALL WScript.Echo("  Scope:            " & NET_FW_SCOPE_ALL_NAME)
>          Case NET_FW_SCOPE_LOCAL_SUBNET WScript.Echo("  Scope:            " & NET_FW_SCOPE_LOCAL_SUBNET_NAME)
>          Case NET_FW_SCOPE_CUSTOM WScript.Echo("  Scope:            " & NET_FW_SCOPE_CUSTOM_NAME)
>       End Select
>
>       WScript.Echo("  RemoteAddresses:  " & app.RemoteAddresses)
>       WScript.Echo("  Enabled:          " & app.Enabled)
>
>       WScript.Echo("")
>
>    Next
>
> else
>
>    WScript.Echo("No Authorized Applications were found for Current Profile.")
>
> end if
> ```

On Vista and later, create an instance of the [`INetFwPolicy2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365309.aspx) COM object and enumerate its [`Rules`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365322.aspx) collection. There is an example on MSDN (in C/C++):

[Enumerating Firewall Rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd339609.aspx)

> This example enumerates firewall rules using the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security APIs.
>
> ```cpp
> /********************************************************************++
> Copyright (C) Microsoft. All Rights Reserved.
>
> Abstract:
>     This C++ file includes sample code for enumerating Windows Firewall
>     rules using the Microsoft Windows Firewall APIs.
>
> ********************************************************************/
>
> #include <windows.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <comutil.h>
> #include <atlcomcli.h>
> #include <netfw.h>
>
> #pragma comment( lib, "ole32.lib" )
> #pragma comment( lib, "oleaut32.lib" )
>
> #define NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP_NAME L"TCP"
> #define NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_UDP_NAME L"UDP"
>
> #define NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN_NAME L"In"
> #define NET_FW_RULE_DIR_OUT_NAME L"Out"
>
> #define NET_FW_RULE_ACTION_BLOCK_NAME L"Block"
> #define NET_FW_RULE_ACTION_ALLOW_NAME L"Allow"
>
> #define NET_FW_RULE_ENABLE_IN_NAME L"TRUE"
> #define NET_FW_RULE_DISABLE_IN_NAME L"FALSE"
>
>
> // Forward declarations
> void        DumpFWRulesInCollection(INetFwRule* FwRule);
> HRESULT     WFCOMInitialize(INetFwPolicy2** ppNetFwPolicy2);
>
>
> int __cdecl main()
> {
>     HRESULT hrComInit = S_OK;
>     HRESULT hr = S_OK;
>
>     ULONG cFetched = 0; 
>     CComVariant var;
>
>     IUnknown *pEnumerator;
>     IEnumVARIANT* pVariant = NULL;
>
>     INetFwPolicy2 *pNetFwPolicy2 = NULL;
>     INetFwRules *pFwRules = NULL;
>     INetFwRule *pFwRule = NULL;
>
>     long fwRuleCount;
>
>     // Initialize COM.
>     hrComInit = CoInitializeEx(
>                     0,
>                     COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED
>                     );
>
>     // Ignore RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE; this just means that COM has already been
>     // initialized with a different mode. Since we don't care what the mode is,
>     // we'll just use the existing mode.
>     if (hrComInit != RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE)
>     {
>         if (FAILED(hrComInit))
>         {
>             wprintf(L"CoInitializeEx failed: 0x%08lx\n", hrComInit);
>             goto Cleanup;
>         }
>     }
>
>     // Retrieve INetFwPolicy2
>     hr = WFCOMInitialize(&pNetFwPolicy2);
>     if (FAILED(hr))
>     {
>         goto Cleanup;
>     }
>
>     // Retrieve INetFwRules
>     hr = pNetFwPolicy2->get_Rules(&pFwRules);
>     if (FAILED(hr))
>     {
>         wprintf(L"get_Rules failed: 0x%08lx\n", hr);
>         goto Cleanup;
>     }
>
>     // Obtain the number of Firewall rules
>     hr = pFwRules->get_Count(&fwRuleCount);
>     if (FAILED(hr))
>     {
>         wprintf(L"get_Count failed: 0x%08lx\n", hr);
>         goto Cleanup;
>     }
>
>     wprintf(L"The number of rules in the Windows Firewall are %d\n", fwRuleCount);
>
>     // Iterate through all of the rules in pFwRules
>     pFwRules->get__NewEnum(&pEnumerator);
>
>     if(pEnumerator)
>     {
>         hr = pEnumerator->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IEnumVARIANT), (void **) &pVariant);
>     }
>
>     while(SUCCEEDED(hr) && hr != S_FALSE)
>     {
>         var.Clear();
>         hr = pVariant->Next(1, &var, &cFetched);
>
>         if (S_FALSE != hr)
>         {
>             if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
>             {
>                 hr = var.ChangeType(VT_DISPATCH);
>             }
>             if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
>             {
>                 hr = (V_DISPATCH(&var))->QueryInterface(__uuidof(INetFwRule), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pFwRule));
>             }
>
>             if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
>             {
>                 // Output the properties of this rule
>                 DumpFWRulesInCollection(pFwRule);
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
> Cleanup:
>
>     // Release pFwRule
>     if (pFwRule != NULL)
>     {
>         pFwRule->Release();
>     }
>
>     // Release INetFwPolicy2
>     if (pNetFwPolicy2 != NULL)
>     {
>         pNetFwPolicy2->Release();
>     }
>
>     // Uninitialize COM.
>     if (SUCCEEDED(hrComInit))
>     {
>         CoUninitialize();
>     }
>
>     return 0;
> }
>
>
> // Output properties of a Firewall rule 
> void DumpFWRulesInCollection(INetFwRule* FwRule)
> {
>     variant_t InterfaceArray;
>     variant_t InterfaceString;  
>
>     VARIANT_BOOL bEnabled;
>     BSTR bstrVal;
>
>     long lVal = 0;
>     long lProfileBitmask = 0;
>
>     NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION fwDirection;
>     NET_FW_ACTION fwAction;
>
>     struct ProfileMapElement 
>     {
>         NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE2 Id;
>         LPCWSTR Name;
>     };
>
>     ProfileMapElement ProfileMap[3];
>     ProfileMap[0].Id = NET_FW_PROFILE2_DOMAIN;
>     ProfileMap[0].Name = L"Domain";
>     ProfileMap[1].Id = NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE;
>     ProfileMap[1].Name = L"Private";
>     ProfileMap[2].Id = NET_FW_PROFILE2_PUBLIC;
>     ProfileMap[2].Name = L"Public";
>
>     wprintf(L"---------------------------------------------\n");
>
>     if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_Name(&bstrVal)))
>     {
>         wprintf(L"Name:             %s\n", bstrVal);
>     }
>
>     if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_Description(&bstrVal)))
>     {
>         wprintf(L"Description:      %s\n", bstrVal);
>     }
>
>     if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_ApplicationName(&bstrVal)))
>     {
>         wprintf(L"Application Name: %s\n", bstrVal);
>     }
>
>     if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_ServiceName(&bstrVal)))
>     {
>         wprintf(L"Service Name:     %s\n", bstrVal);
>     }
>
>     if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_Protocol(&lVal)))
>     {
>         switch(lVal)
>         {
>             case NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP: 
>
>                 wprintf(L"IP Protocol:      %s\n", NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP_NAME);
>                 break;
>
>             case NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_UDP: 
>
>                 wprintf(L"IP Protocol:      %s\n", NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_UDP_NAME);
>                 break;
>
>             default:
>
>                 break;
>         }
>
>         if(lVal != NET_FW_IP_VERSION_V4 && lVal != NET_FW_IP_VERSION_V6)
>         {
>             if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_LocalPorts(&bstrVal)))
>             {
>                 wprintf(L"Local Ports:      %s\n", bstrVal);
>             }
>
>             if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_RemotePorts(&bstrVal)))
>             {
>                 wprintf(L"Remote Ports:      %s\n", bstrVal);
>             }
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_IcmpTypesAndCodes(&bstrVal)))
>             {
>                 wprintf(L"ICMP TypeCode:      %s\n", bstrVal);
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_LocalAddresses(&bstrVal)))
>     {
>         wprintf(L"LocalAddresses:   %s\n", bstrVal);
>     }
>
>     if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_RemoteAddresses(&bstrVal)))
>     {
>         wprintf(L"RemoteAddresses:  %s\n", bstrVal);
>     }
>
>     if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_Profiles(&lProfileBitmask)))
>     {
>         // The returned bitmask can have more than 1 bit set if multiple profiles 
>         //   are active or current at the same time
>
>         for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
>         {
>             if ( lProfileBitmask & ProfileMap[i].Id  )
>             {
>                 wprintf(L"Profile:  %s\n", ProfileMap[i].Name);
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_Direction(&fwDirection)))
>     {
>         switch(fwDirection)
>         {
>             case NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN:
>
>                 wprintf(L"Direction:        %s\n", NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN_NAME);
>                 break;
>
>             case NET_FW_RULE_DIR_OUT:
>
>                 wprintf(L"Direction:        %s\n", NET_FW_RULE_DIR_OUT_NAME);
>                 break;
>
>             default:
>
>                 break;
>         }
>     }
>
>     if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_Action(&fwAction)))
>     {
>         switch(fwAction)
>         {
>             case NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK:
>
>                 wprintf(L"Action:           %s\n", NET_FW_RULE_ACTION_BLOCK_NAME);
>                 break;
>
>             case NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW:
>
>                 wprintf(L"Action:           %s\n", NET_FW_RULE_ACTION_ALLOW_NAME);
>                 break;
>
>             default:
>
>                 break;
>         }
>     }
>
>     if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_Interfaces(&InterfaceArray)))
>     {
>         if(InterfaceArray.vt != VT_EMPTY)
>         {
>             SAFEARRAY    *pSa = NULL;
>
>             pSa = InterfaceArray.parray;
>
>             for(long index= pSa->rgsabound->lLbound; index < (long)pSa->rgsabound->cElements; index++)
>             {
>                 SafeArrayGetElement(pSa, &index, &InterfaceString);
>                 wprintf(L"Interfaces:       %s\n", (BSTR)InterfaceString.bstrVal);
>             }
>         }
>     }
>
>     if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_InterfaceTypes(&bstrVal)))
>     {
>         wprintf(L"Interface Types:  %s\n", bstrVal);
>     }
>
>     if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_Enabled(&bEnabled)))
>     {
>         if (bEnabled)
>         {
>             wprintf(L"Enabled:          %s\n", NET_FW_RULE_ENABLE_IN_NAME);
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             wprintf(L"Enabled:          %s\n", NET_FW_RULE_DISABLE_IN_NAME);
>         }
>     }
>
>     if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_Grouping(&bstrVal)))
>     {
>         wprintf(L"Grouping:         %s\n", bstrVal);
>     }
>
>     if (SUCCEEDED(FwRule->get_EdgeTraversal(&bEnabled)))
>     {
>         if (bEnabled)
>         {
>             wprintf(L"Edge Traversal:   %s\n", NET_FW_RULE_ENABLE_IN_NAME);
>         }
>         else
>         {
>             wprintf(L"Edge Traversal:   %s\n", NET_FW_RULE_DISABLE_IN_NAME);
>         }
>     }
> }
>
>
> // Instantiate INetFwPolicy2
> HRESULT WFCOMInitialize(INetFwPolicy2** ppNetFwPolicy2)
> {
>     HRESULT hr = S_OK;
>
>     hr = CoCreateInstance(
>         __uuidof(NetFwPolicy2), 
>         NULL, 
>         CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
>         __uuidof(INetFwPolicy2), 
>         (void**)ppNetFwPolicy2);
>
>     if (FAILED(hr))
>     {
>         wprintf(L"CoCreateInstance for INetFwPolicy2 failed: 0x%08lx\n", hr);
>         goto Cleanup;        
>     }
>
> Cleanup:
>     return hr;
> }
> ```

Comment: thank you mate, worked! also, i have seen you posting good replies about networking and related things, keep up.